# exc_bad_access when enumerating and adding object to NSMutableSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, enumeration

I keep getting the following exception from time to time when objects are added to a `NSMutableSet`:

```
Thread 6: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

It occurs in the following block of code:

```
- (NSSet *)project:(NSSet *)set
{
    NSMutableSet *collection = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSArray *keys = @[@"proximityUUID", @"major", @"minor"];

    [set enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(ESTBeacon *beacon, BOOL *stop) {
        [collection addObject:[beacon dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys]];
    }];

    return [self alter:collection];
}
```

More precisely on: `[collection addObject:[beacon dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys]];`.

I know that is a memory issue but I'm not sure what is the cause. Could it be the option `NSEnumerationConcurrent` that causes the exception? Or what else could it be?

Also, should I be using other enumeration methods?

**NOTE**: *The above code is run within a `dispatch_async` method, if that is of any help*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various collection classes are not thread safe when it comes to writing while doing other reads or writes. You created a concurrent enumeration which means you end up doing multi-threaded calls to `addObject:` on your `NSMutableSet`. This results in the crash.

Change your enumeration to be serial instead of concurrent.

```
[set enumerateObjectsWithOptions:0 usingBlock:^(ESTBeacon *beacon, BOOL *stop) {
    [collection addObject:[beacon dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys]];
}];
```

Comment: What about code inside `dispatch_async` blocks, does that have to thread safe as well? Or is it fine if operations like the method I added in the post description are running inside the async blocks?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `dispatch_async`. The problem is in your use of a concurrent enumeration that makes calls that are not thread safe.